# Svg and vue.js onload function doesnt get called should I use Mounted?

Tags: vue.js, svg, onload

I am not sure this is where the code will end up but for now I am trying to test making my SVG objects draggable within my vue component. However the draggable code is not executed onload. I get error makeDraggable is defined but never used, however I would only want to use it onload but that doesnt work, I an assuming this is something to do with Vues reactive nature and I should try and call it on mounted or something ?

```
<template>
  <div class="spaceview">
    <h2>Space Man !</h2>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="400"
      height="1800"
      id="space"
      onload="makeDraggable(evt)"
    >
      <g
        v-for="(note, index) in notes"
        :key="index"
        :transform="`translate(0, ${index * 170})`"
        class="draggable"
      >
        <rect height="120" width="80" fill="#f0b375"></rect>
        <text y="15">{{ note.text }}</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'YourData',
  computed: mapState({
    notes: state => state.notes
  })
}
// drag code for now included in SpaceView

function makeDraggable(evt) {
  console.log('yo')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use Vue's `@load=` event instead of `onload=`.

```
 <svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="400"
  height="1800"
  id="space"
  @load="makeDraggable"
>
```

You also don't need to call it as a function and pass `evt`, vue will do that for you.

Comment: ah cool, thank you, sorry can you explain the not call as a function please ?

Comment: @adamprocter When you pass a string to any `event`, Vue will call it as a function.

Comment: so where do I put my makeDraggable code now ? do I need to move into mounted ?

Comment: No. It does a lookup on functions defined in `methods: {}` object of the Component.

Comment: Once last thought - How can I use the evt ? that Vue provides in my method if I need it ?

Comment: Yep. It passes the event to you automatically. Try logging it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194337/discussion-between-adamprocter-and-ohgodwhy).

Comment: Am still stuck with this I can’t find much on @load to understand what it does, but can’t call the method. Code can be seen here for now https://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk/adamprocter/couchdocs/blob/nativesvg/src/components/SpaceView.vue